# How do I identify application identifiers and their values from a GS1 2D Barcode (2D Datamatrix)?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, barcode-scanner, gs1-datamatrix

I am attempting to identify values from a 2D barcode for parsing within a piece of software.

Essentially, when scanning 2D barcodes, I obtain an incomprehensible string such as:

```
011234567890123410abcde21fghijk17200101
```

I have managed to program a couple of scanners to 'identify' the application identifiers by encasing them in parentheses such as:

```
(01)12345678901234(10)abcde(21)fghijk(17)200101
```

This requires a configuration change to the scanners, but I'd like my software rather than my hardware to identify the values, rather than relying on proprietary scanners to do the work for me.

I have got as far as lifting out Group Separators from variable length fields, then I have seem to have come stuck.

Any and all help appreciated, I have been racking my brain for days. Our languages of choice are C# & Javascript, but if anybody has the *logic*, even if it's pseudocode, that would be more than helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your problem, this document [GS1 DataMatrix Guideline](https://www.gs1.org/docs/barcodes/GS1_DataMatrix_Guideline.pdf) distributed by GS 1 will be of help.

Directly there is an answer in the flow chart on page 18.
However, you will need to read other parts as well.

In any case, deleting something like a group separator makes it impossible to solve the problem.
Please obtain and retain all the information and then process it.

Comment: Thank you, in the raft of documentation I missed this flow chart. I have read this document a few times in the past and somehow forgot it existed. I appreciate the time you have taken to help.